# Determining whether an unregistered user is first visiting app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

So I am trying to understand how I can track whether or not a user has visited the app before so I can implement some of my UX scenarios.

I understand that if I have a user register, I can use some sort of boolean key to toggle if they have finished their registration and show them a custom welcome message or modal. However for this app, you do not need to register. For the normal user, they can download the app and use it. You only need to register if you are a business owner and would like your business to be displayed in the results.

Is it possible to track if a user has visited an app before if they do not need to register? I am new to app development and these are just small little scenarios I am trying to figure out how to handle. If you know of any good tutorials regarding tracking this or even some code samples it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be using Ionic Storage, and storing a variable within the phone. However, I am not sure what happens if the user deletes the app. Good reading here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/.

On your home page you can try:

```
//Check if they have visited the app before.
 storage.get('hasVisited').then((key) => { //User has visited the app before
 //Do logic for when user has visited before in here
})
.catch(err => {
//First time visiting. So, set the key:
 storage.set('hasVisited',true).then(() => {
 //We set the key in storage.
}

});
```

Comment: Hey this is great! Thanks!